# Not working join operation

Tags: unix, join

I have a file as follows:

```
AKT3
ARRB1
ATF2
ATF4
BDNF
BRAF
C00076
C00165
TNF
TNFRSF1A
TP53
TRAF2
TRAF6
```

To me, it is perfectly sorted. Is not? Also, I have another file which contains AKT3, BRAF, TRAF6, etc. as its first column element. Since this file is too big, I do not put it here. However, after I type:

```
LANG=en_EN join -j 1 file2 file1 > output -t $'\t'
```

output file contains these lines:

```
TRAF6   0   genome...
TRAF6   0   genome...
TRAF6   0   genome...
TRAF6   0   genome...
```

I must see other rows which start with AKT3, BRAF, etc. as well in this output but there are only TRAF6 lines. What is the problem? How can I get the proper output? Thanks.

Edit: You can get the big file from this link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/a2dmsq1tskpb9vg/sorted_mutation_data?dl=0

It is about 25 MB. I am sorry for this.

Edit (2): Lets say...
File1:

```
ADA
ADAM
BRUCE
GARY
```

File2:

```
AB 1
ABA 2
ABB 3
ADA 4
ADA 5
EVE 6
EVE 7
EVE 8 
GARY 9
GARY 10
```

The output should be:

```
ADA 4
ADA 5
GARY 9
GARY 10
```

Edit: The problem was caused by non-printable ASCII characters that were hiden in the text in a way. After removed them all, I could use "join".

Comment: What output file do you want to achieve?

Comment: For each row of file2, if file2's first column element which is written in file1, the output file should contain the whole row (of file2). I will edit the question in two minutes.

Comment: Check "Edit (2)" section of my question please.

Comment: yes, got it. Will get back to you with an answer

Comment: Actually this is what join command should do. There should be something wrong with my input files. If you have time, please work on original inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I don't know what your environment is, but this for me (I use an explicit sort to be sure it will work, and also to reveal what happens when you sort by the whole line in the default collating order instead of an explicit field).

Note also I have no `-t $'\t'` on the statement with the `join` command.  If your second file has tab-separated fields then you'll need to express that correctly with a real tab character, and with the option before the filenames, and also you may have to be sure your files are sorted with the same key and field separator.

```
#! /bin/sh

f1=$(mktemp -t jdata)
f2=$(mktemp -t jdata)

trap "RC=$?; rm -f $f1 $f2*; exit $RC" 0 1 2 3 15

sort > $f1 <<__EOF__
ADA
ADAM
BRUCE
GARY
__EOF__

sort > $f2 <<__EOF__
AB 1
ABA 2
ABB 3
ADA 4
ADA 5
EVE 6
EVE 7
EVE 8 
GARY 9
GARY 10
__EOF__

join -j 1 $f1 $f2
```

sh ./tjoin-multi.sh

```
ADA 4
ADA 5
GARY 10
GARY 9
```